# WooCommerce Shop Page Not Found 404

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I added WooCommerce to my WordPress site and the Shop page is giving a 404.  This seems weird because the page is listed in my "Pages" area like this "Shop - Shop Page", but when I try to preview it is not found.  I tried uninstalling and reinstalling WooCommerce and also deleted the Shop page and recreated one using the WooCommerce tools.  I also fiddled with the permalinks page (screenshot below), but no luck. --Also the Cart Page and other woocommerce pages are not working.  Thanks for any guidance you can give on this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done here is changing slug for products. For example : http://localhost:8080/shop/product-category/sample-product as explained in WP, but not your Woocommerce home. Change the base to base default in permalinks settings. Then read after :)

If you want to change your "Shop Homepage" go to http://localhost:8080/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=products&section=display

That's the good way to do it !